# Importing Data to Contentful programatically from a json file

Tags: api, import, contentful

I am trying to import some data programatically into contentful:

I am following the docs [here](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/cli/import-and-export/)

And running the command inside my integrated terminal

```
contentful space import --config config.json
```

Where the config file is

```
{
  "spaceId": "abc123",
  "managementToken": "112323132321adfWWExample",
  "contentFile": "./dataToImport.json"
}
```

And the dataToImport.json file is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "address": "11234 New York City"
    },
    {
      "address": "1212 New York City"
    }
  ]
}
```

The thing is I don't understand what format my dataToImport.json should be and what is missing inside this file or in my config file so that the array of addresses from the .json file get added as **new entries** to an already created content model inside the Contentful UI show in the screenshot below

[image]

I am not specifying the content model for the data to go into so I believe that is one issue, and I don't know how I do that. An example or repo would help me out greatly

Answer (score 1):

The types of data you can import are listed : [in their documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/cli/import-and-export/#:%7E:text=Importing%20content,options%5D%20from%20your%20command%20line.&text=Similar%20to%20the%20export%20tool,in%20an%20external%20json%20file.)

your json top level should say "entries" and not data, if new content of a content type is what you would like to import.

This is an example of a blog post as per content model of the tutorial they provide.
The only thing i didn't work out yet is where the user id is :D so i substituted for one of the content type 'person' also provided in their tutorial (I think it's called Gatsby Starter)

```
{"entries": [
{
  "sys": {
    "space": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Space",
        "id": "theSpaceIdToReceiveYourImport"
      }
    },    
    "type": "Entry",
    "createdAt": "2019-04-17T00:56:24.722Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-27T09:11:56.769Z",
    "environment": {
      "sys": {
        "id": "master",
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Environment"
      }
    },
    "publishedVersion": 149, -- these are not compulsory, you can skip 
    "publishedAt": "2019-04-27T09:11:56.769Z", --  you can skip
    "firstPublishedAt": "2019-04-17T00:56:28.525Z", --  you can skip
    "publishedCounter": 3, --  you can skip
    "version": 150,
    "publishedBy": { -- this is an example of a linked content
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "person",
        "id": "personId"
      }
    },
    "contentType": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "ContentType",
        "id": "blogPost" -- here should be your content type 'RealtorProperties'
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": { -- here should go your content type fields, i can't see it in your post
            "title": {
                "en-US": "Test 1"
            },
            "slug": {
                "en-US": "Test-1"
            },
            
            "description": {
                "en-US": "some description"
            },
            "body": {
                "en-US": "some body..."
            },
           
            "publishDate": {
                "en-US": "2016-12-19"
            },  
            "heroImage": { -- another example of a linked content
              "en-US": {
                "sys": {
                  "type": "Link",
                  "linkType": "Asset",
                  "id": "idOfTHisImage"
                }
                }
            }
  }
},
--another entry, ...]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [repo](https://github.com/contentful/content-models). I am also trying to figure this out. Looks like there's quite a lot of fields that need to be included in the json file. I was hoping there'd be a simple solution but it seems you (me too actually) will need to create scripts to "convert" your json file to data contentful can read and import.
I'll let you know if I find anything better.